# How to retrain a neural network in Keras without restart the jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, jupyter-notebook

I constructed a simple neural network using Keras. And when I run it in jupyter notebook for the first time, I works perfectly well. But If I rerun it without changing anything, some problems happens. The following two pictures showing the screenshot for the first time and second time respectively. You can see the difference.
[image]
[image]
I'm a newbie to Keras and have searched the Internet for several hours. What should I do so that I can rerun the neural network without restart jupyter notebook? Thanks！

Comment: why you don't want to restart the notebook?

Comment: try re-defining the model instead of just running the `.fit` function.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Actually, I tried re-defining the model, but the training result for the re-defining model is the same as the second picture. Is there something tricky?

Comment: i honestly don't know, ive never tried this before.

Comment: @Bicheng Are you sure you have not executed/changed anything in between since the cell numbers are 33 and 42?

Comment: Please do **not** open [multiple questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54050656/how-to-fit-run-the-neural-network-multiple-times-in-jupyter-notebook) on the same issue! Edit & update your initial question instead!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fit/run the neural network multiple times in jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54050656/how-to-fit-run-the-neural-network-multiple-times-in-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard code we use to reset the session before training again.

```
from keras import backend as K

curr_session = tf.get_default_session()
# close current session
if curr_session is not None:
    curr_session.close()
# reset graph
K.clear_session()
# create new session
s = tf.InteractiveSession()
K.set_session(s)
```