# Keras: Performance of model.fit() when shuffle=False or True

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, shuffle, epoch

In Keras, when we are training a model for a fixed number of epochs using `model.fit()`, one of its parameters is `shuffle` (a boolean). The Keras documentation about it reads:

> "Boolean (whether to shuffle the training data before each epoch)."

Essentially, I am training a Convolutional Neural Network and trying to get reproducible results. So, I followed the instructions and specified seeds as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659482/why-cant-i-get-reproducible-results-in-keras-even-though-i-set-the-random-seeds/52897289#52897289).

Although it worked partially (successfully got reproducible results on my local machine only), it was thought setting `shuffle=False` would help (by keeping the same data inputs), but keeping the reproducibility aside for a second, doing that dramatically reduced the performance of the model. Specifically, after each epoch, the metrics give same results (meaning not improving) even an increase in epochs gives same numbers (**Accuracy = ~75 after 3 epochs and after 30 epochs**). But setting `shuffle=True` shows gradual normal improvement in results.

Training data shape: `(143256, 1, 150, 3)`
Target data shape: `(143256, 3)`
Batch Size: `64`

```
metrics = ['accuracy']

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                      optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                      metrics=metrics)
....

model.fit(x_train, to_categorical(y_train), batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs, verbose=verbose,
          validation_data=(x_val, to_categorical(y_val)),
          shuffle=False, callbacks=[metrics],
          class_weight=class_weights)
```

1. Is this normal behavior of shuffling being set to false? Because even though the data is not permuted, the weights should be updated in each epoch and hence the metrics should improve overtime.
2. Assuming there is some issue with my implementation, should there be any significant difference in model performance when trying to train with both approaches (shuffling or without it)?
3. How can the results be reproducible with `shuffle=True`, which they apparently are, even if seeds are specified?

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You wrote "Specifically, after each epoch, the metrics give same results (meaning not improving)" result on traning or validation set? Please provide code.

Comment: I've edited the post to add the portion of code.. What's weird is, everything works as expected when `shuffle=True`. And yes, the metrics are calculated on validation set.

Comment: How is your data? Is it grouped (same data together)? If so, similar data will have similar error and the gradients during that data will optimize the weights for those certain minibatches, and will change for the next group. This will also reflect on validation. By shuffeling, you are making the network generalize better, so the outputs will gradually be optimized and more general.

Comment: @SajanGohil No, it is not grouped.. But there is a huge class imbalance (3 classes with ratio ~0.77, 0.18,0.05). Can that be the reason..?

Answer (score 0):

Might be very late on this but came upon it and did not see any answers so thought I will pitch in!!

1. Traditionally speaking, unless you are not working on time-series data and specifically understanding the historical patterns that look at sequences for trends, shuffling the input data before fitting the model is a good idea. It helps reduce the order bias and improve cross-validation. It works better when dealing with an imbalanced dataset. There are multiple discussions done over this in [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245502/why-should-we-shuffle-data-while-training-a-neural-network) as well as [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24511/why-should-the-data-be-shuffled-for-machine-learning-tasks) that you can have a look for more information.
2. there should not be much difference unless the dataset in highly imbalanced and the splits of the train test are not carefully done. In theory, the shuffle should produce better and more robust models.
3. This is a bit tricky to understand. I might be wrong here but Shuffling can be done in many different ways. It is a random process. however, setting a seed maintains the shuffle pattern. so every time when a seed is used, it shuffles in exact same way. removing seed will shuffle in different ways. For instance in input data is `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, then setting a seed will result in shuffle `[3,5,6,1,4,2]` every time. But not setting seed will have following result for two shuffles `[1,5,4,3,6,2]` `[5,2,4,6,3,1]`