# I can't get reproducible results with keras neural networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

As the title says. I'm currently working in python (3.11) with keras (2.12.0) and tensorflow (2.12.1, cpu-only package) libraries, and I'm facing some problems with the reproducibility of my neural networks; currently coding in jupyter notebook. I'm using a limited amount of libraries, as I am working in an enviroment. This is the scenario:

1. I import some data with pandas.
2. I train the model on a subset of the data, using the rest for testing.
3. I get different results each time I restart the kernel and fit the model.

Now, I think I'm properly setting the seeds. I read the keras documentation, the faq section on how to get reproducible results (https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/), and similar questions being asked here ([How to get reproducible results in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419510/how-to-get-reproducible-results-in-keras), [Why can't I get reproducible results in Keras even though I set the random seeds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659482/why-cant-i-get-reproducible-results-in-keras-even-though-i-set-the-random-seeds)), but nothing seems to work.

I believe I did everything properly, in particular:

1. I set all kinds of seeds that are mentioned;
2. I made sure the weights are initialized the same using seeds;
3. I enabled_op_determinism, even though I'm not using the CPU, and set the PYTHONHASHSEED (i did it within the program, so that may be the problem as it's said I must do it beforehand).

Everytime I restart the kernel, the following happens:

1. I load the data (correctly)
2. Split in train-test (seeded, so it's the same everytime)
3. Create the model: I check and make sure the initial weights are the same, even the bias.
4. I fit the model: once I restart the kernel, the fit history changes slightly.

The last point is the one that confuses me. WHEN I DON'T restart the kernel, and run the model definition + estimation, I get the very same fit history each time (as I said, it's seeded). WHEN I RESTART THE KERNEL, i run everything again, and everything works up to point 3. of the last list, but then the fit history changes. How does that work? I thought it was the compiler, I am using ADAM, but I don't know? Why would that cause a problem?

I am currently stumped, I would like everything to be the same every run of the script, as I am doing simulations, and I need the results to be reproducible.

```
import os  #Necessario per la riproducibilità
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'

import random    #Random seed
random.seed(5014)

import numpy as np
np.random.seed(5014)

#Pacchetti generici
import sys
import feather   #Per leggere i dataset
import time

#Reti neurali
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(5014)
#tf.compat.v1.set_random_seed(5014)

import keras
keras.utils.set_random_seed(5014) #This should set again all of the seeds above, I know, but I'm trying everything.

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import math
print(sys.version)
```

```
#This isn't enough to get the same results.
tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()

from keras import backend as K
session_conf = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

```
#Loading the data
data = feather.read_dataframe("dataset1.feather")  #pd.DataFrame
data.shape

#This is to get the model
def create_model(size, n_input):
    #Per rendere la stima replicabile
    seeds= [1000,1001,1002,1003]
    print("\nSemi utilizzati per l'iniz: ")
    print(seeds)

    #Struttura del modello
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(size[0], input_shape=(n_input,), activation ="relu", name="Hidden1", kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(seed = seeds[0])))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(size[1], activation='relu', name="Hidden2", kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(seed = seeds[1])))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(size[2], activation='relu', name="Hidden3", kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(seed = seeds[2])))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear", name="Output", kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(seed = seeds[3])))

    #Metodo di stima da utilizzare
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='Adam', metrics = ["mean_squared_error"])
    
    return model
```

These are functions used in the code.

```
vars = set(data.columns)
escluse = {"output","Days"}
X = vars.difference(escluse)

#Le posizioni di Days e output
days_pos = data.shape[1]
out_pos = data.shape[1]-1

#Specifiche della rete neurale
reps = 3 #Numero di punti di partenza per ciascuna rete.
size = [200,200,200]

i = 365
    
print("\nCurrently: ",i)
data_to_use = data.loc[(data["Days"]<=i) & (data["Days"] >= (i-364))]

#Definire i dataset da usare per stima
train, val = train_test_split(data_to_use, test_size=0.2)
x_train = train[list(X)]
y_train = train["output"]
x_val = val[list(X)]
y_val = val["output"]

model_nn = create_model(size,data_to_use.shape[1] - 2)
```

Up to the lines above, everything works as it should, the model is the same everytime I restart the kernel.
But then, when it comes time for

```
storia = model_nn.fit(x = x_train, y = y_train, batch_size = math.ceil(x_train.shape[0]/2), epochs = 1000, validation_data=(x_val,y_val), verbose =0, 
                callbacks = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor ="val_mean_squared_error", min_delta =0, patience =8))

storia.history["val_mean_squared_error"][0:5]
```

The history changes. Why? If I repeat model definition + fitting, I get the same exact results. If I restart the kernel, and run everythin again, the results change. Does anyone know how to solve it? The data is here: https://github.com/marco-pll/data-STACKoverflow.

Please, and thanks for the help. I'm about to cry.

EDIT: It was, in fact, the PYTHONHASHSEED. Just needed to put it as environment variable. Leaving the post here, as it may help someone else.

Comment: Just FYI,. train_test_split has a property called "random_state" You may want to set that to a number.

Comment: While it is a good idea to use `random_state` inside `train_test_split`, it should not matter in this example, as sklearn uses numpy under the hood and if you set `np.random.seed()`, you get the same split for `train_test_split`.

Comment: It would also be a good idea to set the edit as an (accepted) answer, even if there is no reasoning with it. In its current state, the edit part is quickly overlooked and it seems that this is an unanswered question.